# Copy horizontal range to another google sheet based on specific cell status

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I am trying - unsuccessfully - to write a script to simplify the function I pasted below.

Its purpose is to check if the status cell has been updated to "Booking Confirmed" and then copy a portion of its corresponding row to another sheet.

```
=IF('Finals Worksheet'!$N$5 = "Booking confirmed", importrange("//spreadsheet key//","Finals Worksheet!H11:M11"),"")
```

I'd also like to remove the spreadsheet key and have it call from any sheet it is used in.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried already?

Comment: This is my most recent attempt:

function importSession(a) {
  var finalS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Finals Worksheet');
  var S = finalS.getRange('Status').getValues()
  var finData = finalS.getRange(3, 9, finalS.getLastRow(), 5);
  
    if (S[(a-1)] == "Booking Confirmed") {
  
      return finData[a-1]
  }
}